# Hugo site starts locally, only displays 404 on hosted GH page

Tags: github-pages, hugo

My Hugo site starts locally, but only returns a 404.html page when hit on GitHub Pages.

I've tried re-instantiating the repo, rebuilding the site with different commands, pushing and deploying with the Hugo deploy script, and `rm -rf` the public folder and re-adding it.

Repository: `https://github.com/jschalz/jschalz.github.io`

When following the [tutorial](https://gohugo.io/hosting-and-deployment/hosting-on-github/), running `git submodule add -b master git@github.com:jschalz/jschalz.github.io.git public`:

```
'public' already exists in the index
```

Currently hosted at `https://jschalz.github.io`.

I'd expect the site to come up with my pages (and I definitely have non-draft pages on there), but it's only returning 404.html. It's possible it's because I renamed the repo at one point, but I'm not sure. Troubleshooting ideas are very appreciated.

UPDATE: The issue was that I didn't have an index.html, index.xml, or README.md in my repo. Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

2022: A different approach [uses now GitHub Actions](https://gohugo.io/hosting-and-deployment/hosting-on-github/#build-hugo-with-github-action), since those are the [default to build GitHub pages, since Aug. 2022](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73311701/6309).

Hence the new section "[Build Hugo With GitHub Action](https://gohugo.io/hosting-and-deployment/hosting-on-github/#build-hugo-with-github-action)" and the [GitHub `actions/hugo-setup`](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/hugo-setup).

---

Original answer 2019:

> The issue was that I didn't have an `index.html`, `index.xml`, or `README.md` in my repo. Fixed.

Not exactly fixed.

The [point of the tutorial](https://gohugo.io/hosting-and-deployment/hosting-on-github/#step-by-step-instructions) was:

```
git submodule add -b master git@github.com:<USERNAME>/<USERNAME>.github.io.git public
```

> This creates a git submodule.
> Now when you run the `hugo` command to build your site to `public`, the created `public` directory will have a different remote origin (i.e. hosted GitHub repository).

Meaning what you should be pushing if, from your `public` subfolder, only what Hugo has generated.

You should *not* push your Hugo project (`config.toml`, `themes`, and so on): those should be pushed in a separate GitHub repository for safekeeping and versionning.

Comment: I actually had added the submodule and been pushing from it with the tutorial's deployment script, but I think I hadn't included a readme or index that GH pages could pick up.

Comment: @ladygremlin Yes, but I still believe your fix is not the correct one: your master branch should only reflect the files from your `public` folder, nothing else.

Comment: [here](https://gohugo.io/hosting-and-deployment/hosting-on-github/#change-baseurl-in-configtoml) one should change `config.toml` so it is probably needed for gh pages and not just `public`.

Comment: [Is the action.yml](https://gohugo.io/hosting-and-deployment/hosting-on-github/#build-hugo-with-github-action) file needed or is it enough to have a `docs` folder where the published html is? I think that - in contrast to e.g. `netlify` - gh pages does not convert the sources to `docs` dir with `hugo` cmd but expects html files in `docs`. So it is `docs` and not `public`.Another thing: the `submodule` cmd does not exist in the current tutorial, did the hugos leave it?

Comment: [Regarding building of static sites](https://docs.github.com/en/pages/getting-started-with-github-pages/about-github-pages#static-site-generators):If you want to use a static site generator other than Jekyll, we recommend that you write a GitHub Actions to build and publish your site instead. So I can choose between building locally or via `github actions` on the github server.

Comment: @Timo Exactly [GitHub Actions](https://github.blog/changelog/2022-07-27-github-pages-custom-github-actions-workflows-beta/) are now recommended to build GitHub Pages. I [mention it here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73311701/6309)