# Publish again unpublished github pages project

Tags: github-pages

I un-published a repo in my account which was hosting using GitHub pages.

Now I want to publish it again, I cannot find any related option in GitHub pages settings.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can re-publish your GitHub Pages website by navigating to the Actions tab of your repository, click on the Pages build and deployment workflow, then click the Re-run all jobs button located in the upper right corner of the page. After the workflow run has completed, your site will be published.

Answer (score 2):

if u lost the republish button . don't worry go to actions. click pages build and deployment , then re-run all jobs pages.your site is published again
[github screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5GRwJ.png)

Answer (score 2):

#### 1. Take Action Tab on github.
  2. Select Latest Workflow.
  3. Click on  Re-run all jobs button.

wait 2 minutes.

Comment: what is the difference from what you wrote and the accepted answer

Answer (score 1):

It might be a side-effect of the recent (Aug. 22, 2022) decision to [Deprecate the theme picker](https://github.blog/changelog/2022-08-22-github-pages-deprecating-the-theme-picker/) for GitHub Pages:

That means there is no more "Choose a theme" button, and GitHub pages are now supposed to be published through a [GitHub Actions workflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73311701/6309), using one of the [starter workflow for GitHub Pages publication](https://github.com/actions/starter-workflows/tree/main/pages).

Answer (score 1):

Navigate to "Actions"

[Actions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rXx1f.png)

Click on New Work Flow

Go to bottom of page

In page section choose "Static HTML"

[Static html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QgUmc.png)

Click Configure & commit changes.

Go go Actions Again, on left most choose "Deploy with Static HTML"

Click "Run Workflow" on right most.

[Run Workflow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V1BmQ.png)